# How to do this motion graphics?

Tags: after-effects, plugins, motion-graphics

This is the motion titling of a film.

I'd like to know few things. Assuming it's created using **Afer Effects**:

- If you give a closer look, you could see ink spreading after it's written. How did they achieve it?
- Was there any plug-in used for this purpose? If yes, which one?

Comment: You could perhaps do it with turbulent displace + blur + curves on the alpha channel (all built in). Trapcode Particular (3rd party) also springs to mind.

Comment: _Curves_ on the alpha channel; can you explain a bit? @stib

Answer (score 3):

If I have to make this manually, I would do the following:

1. Create/Draw the blue Logo in Illustrator as its seen in the final frame.
2. Breakdown and place spread ink into separate layers, like 4 or more.

To make the drawing animation, create a path "using pen tool" along the lines of the blue Logo, make sure that the path is thick enough to cover the lines.
Using **Trim Path** effect you can animate the path and as it spread it reveals the blue Logo, kinda like a mask.
The spread of ink is not that obvious, I think it was made using opacity. So whenever you reveal a letter or two, keyframe the opacity of the layer that contains spread ink that you made earlier in Illustrator from 0% to 100% which creates a feel like a spread.
I hope what I wrote does make sense.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not marking it as the answer because I'd like to see other people's ideas (if there are any). @MEGA

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the Quickdraw plugin - you create your artwork, then paint masks over it in the order that you'd like to reveal the elements.  It then animates the masks for you, and makes it easy to tweak the speeds of the reveals of each stroke

http://aescripts.com/quickdraw/

I'd do the main paths as one layer, then go back and do the ink splatters spreading as a second layer